# Entity Framework 6 IN condition with multi-dimensional object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a list of objects that have many properties. I would like to write a EF6 query that pulls all records matching a specific property in the object list.

This is what I have a it is not working.

`userRoles` is my `List<>` and `RoleID` is the property I want to check against the `RoleId` of the entity.

```
List<DataAccess.Entities.DB.StorageContainerRole> 
    containerRoles = db.StorageContainerRoles
                       .Where(x => userRoles.Select(y => y.RoleID.Value)
                       .Contains(x.RoleId.Value))
                       .Include(z => z.StorageContainer)
                       .ToList();
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'DataAccess.Entities.DB.UserRole'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Did you check your data? Your query looks ok.

Comment: I added the error to my question

Comment: Assign `userRoles.Select(y => y.RoleID.Value)` to variable outside the query and use the variable inside (EF6 requirement).

Answer (score 2):

When you have the list of the user roles already fetched, you can build a list of ids and check this list in your query:

```
IList<int> userRoleIds = userRoles.Select(it => it.RoleId.Value).ToList();

IList<StorageContainerRole> containerRoles = db.StorageContainerRoles
    .Include(z => z.StorageContainer)
    .Where(x => userRoleIds.Contains(x.RoleId))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

EF should translate your query to SQL and it doesn't know what to do with complex (non Primitive) structures.
So for your example you can do `userRoles.Select(y => y.RoleID.Value)` outside of your query this will gives you collection of Primitive types, that should be EF can parse.

In more complex cases, e.g. `x.RoleId == a && x.RoleType == b` you should force EF to build SQL clause as `OR` chain: `WHERE (roleid = 1 AND roletype = 7) OR (roleid = 2 AND roletype = 8)` check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46227467/514449) it explains how to build `OR` query on a simple example with extensions code provided

Comment: The variables you use doesn't make sense, because you are overwriting the variable you are running your foreach loop on. Also the combination of `.Where()` statements is build with `AND`, not with `OR`

Comment: Wrong variable name. Regarding `AND`  you are right. Thanks